# Everything in pinkish in cycles or "Scene World"

Tags: world

[image]

I've been looking back at my blender projects and now all of them are completely pinkish when rendering with cycles (including in the live preview mode)

Also if I'm in LookDev mode and tick "Scene World" under "Shading/Lighting" everything also goes pinkish.

In the World area I am using a HDR file but there doesn't seem to be anything pink there.

Comment: **The magenta color normally indicates missing textures**. Since your whole scene is magenta, it's possibly the HDRi image that is either broken, unreadable due to incompatibility or cannot be found at the given path. Try to reopen the HDRi image, if that doesn't work, try a different HDRi image from [hdrihaven.com](https://hdrihaven.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like metaphor_set mentioned the HDRI image couldn't be found at the given path. I had moved the contents of my Downloads folder to another folder because it had been getting too crowded.